# Better solution than the naive O(n*log(n)) approach

Tags: algorithm

you are given a string consisting of only 1's. eg: "11111111"
you have an iterator that changes direction when it hits the extremes of the string. starting in the direction left to right.
the iterator replaces the next immediate '1' in its path with a zero and then skips to the '1' following that. This goes on until there is only one '1' remaining in the string.
you have to print the location of that '1'.

here is a python 3 code with the naive solution (it also prints the steps for understanding the problem, although steps are not required for the expected answer):

```
n=int(input("enter the number of people in the row : "))
assert(n>=1)
input_string="1"*n
print(input_string)
direction=1
iterator=0
count=0
while(count!=1):
  count=0
  next_to_delete=-1
  while(iterator<len(input_string) and iterator>=0):
    if(input_string[iterator]=='1'):
      if(next_to_delete==-1):
        next_to_delete=iterator
      else:
        input_string=input_string[:iterator]+"0"+input_string[iterator+1:]
        #i.e. input_string[iterator]='0'
        next_to_delete=-1
      count+=1
    iterator+=direction
  print(input_string)
  direction=1 if direction==-1 else -1
  iterator+=direction
print("answer is : ",end='')
print(next_to_delete+1)
```

example:

```
if n=4::::::::::
1111
1010
0010
answer is : 3

if n=5::::::::::
11111
10101
10001
10000
answer is : 1
```

Comment: According to your description, the last remaining `1` is the last character in the string.

Comment: You need to do a few simple examples by hand to see what the pattern is. Worst case you, should be able to do this in O(logn). But there may even be a O(1) answer.

Comment: the last element is not always the answer. for example 11 would yield 10 i.e. 1 will be the solution and not 2.

Comment: It would help to post step-by-step examples for n=4 and n=5. As melpomene indicated, the description is a little vague.

Comment: sorry for that, to give a better understanding i have provided the code. here is a [link](https://repl.it/repls/WorstPalatableSiskin) to run the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a log(n) solution:

```
def survivor_number(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        n -= 1
    b = 2
    t = 1
    while b <= n:
       t += b & n
       b *= 4
    return t
```

This is based on the algorithm in OEIS for [sequence A090569](http://oeis.org/A090569)